filtering a pandas dataframe string column using the `str.contains` method
I have dataframe looking like this, where long_category reflects the category of businesses in the rows:
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'long_category': {0: 'Doctors, Traditional Chinese Medicine, Naturopathic/Holistic, Acupuncture, Health & Medical, Nutritionists',
  1: 'Shipping Centers, Local Services, Notaries, Mailbox Centers, Printing Services',
  2: 'Department Stores, Shopping, Fashion, Home & Garden, Electronics, Furniture Stores',
  3: 'Restaurants, Food, Bubble Tea, Coffee & Tea, Bakeries',
  4: 'Brewpubs, Breweries, Food',
  5: 'Burgers, Fast Food, Sandwiches, Food, Ice Cream & Frozen Yogurt, Restaurants',
  6: 'Sporting Goods, Fashion, Shoe Stores, Shopping, Sports Wear, Accessories',
  7: 'Synagogues, Religious Organizations',
  8: 'Pubs, Restaurants, Italian, Bars, American (Traditional), Nightlife, Greek',
  9: 'Ice Cream & Frozen Yogurt, Fast Food, Burgers, Restaurants, Food'}})

df:

My goal is to shorten those categories into the below known_categories based on whether or not a long category contains a keyword in the known_categories:
  known_categories = ['restaurant', 'beauty & spas', 'hotels', 'health & medical', 'shopping', 'coffee & tea','automotive', 'pets|veterinian', 'services', 'stores',  'grocery', 'ice cream']

So, I do:
df['short_category'] = np.nan
for cat in known_categories:
    excluded_cats = [x for x in known_categories if x!= cat]
    df['short_category'] [ ~(df.long_category.str.contains('|'.join(excluded_cats), regex = True, case = False, na = False)) & (df.long_category.str.contains(cat, regex = True, case = False, na = False))] = cat

It is important that the short categories are mutually exclusive. For example, row indexed 3 should be put in either "restaurant" or "coffee & tea" short category, hence the ~(df.long_category.str.contains('|'.join(excluded_cats), regex = True, case = False, na = False)) condition above.
But this is not working as can be seen below. For example, both of the last two rows have "restaurant" in their long category but only the first one's short category has captured that. I was expecting the last one to be either 'restaurant' or 'ice cream' because it has those keywords from short_categories. So, where have I gone wrong? As a side note, I would like to be able to impact the frequency of the short categories by moving the category further to the front or back of known_categories if possible. For example, with the current short_categories, I'd like the last row to have 'restaurant' as short category. But if I move 'ice cream' before 'restaurant' in short_categories, I would like the last row to show 'ice cream' and not 'restaurant'


You typically shouldn't need a loop here. You can directly craft a regex to extract the keywords.

Go through your categories list backwards (assuming more specific categories come later) and only set it as the short category if no previous category has been assigned:
df['short_category'] = ''

for cat in known_categories[::-1]:
    contains_cat = df['long_category'].str.contains(cat, case = False, regex = True)
    no_category = df['short_category'] == ''

    df.loc[contains_cat & no_category, 'short_category'] = cat


Thanks for this concise solution. I assume the point in [::-1] is just to incorporate the assumption that  more specific categories come later (which does not have to be the case here)

Yes, you could also list it in higher priority to lower priority and then remove the list reversal.

You need to extractall, then order the categories with a Categorical and get the preferred one with groupby.min:
import re

known_categories = ['restaurant', 'beauty & spas', 'hotels', 'health & medical',
                    'shopping', 'coffee & tea','automotive', 'pets|veterinian',
                    'services', 'stores',  'grocery', 'ice cream']

# craft the regex
pattern = r'(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(known_categories,
                             key=len, reverse=True)))

cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=known_categories, ordered=True)

df['short_category'] = (df['long_category'].str.lower()
                        .str.extractall(pattern)[0]
                        .astype(cat).groupby(level=0).min()
                       )

Output:
                                       long_category    short_category
0  Doctors, Traditional Chinese Medicine, Naturop...  health & medical
1  Shipping Centers, Local Services, Notaries, Ma...          services
2  Department Stores, Shopping, Fashion, Home & G...          shopping
3  Restaurants, Food, Bubble Tea, Coffee & Tea, B...        restaurant
4                          Brewpubs, Breweries, Food               NaN
5  Burgers, Fast Food, Sandwiches, Food, Ice Crea...        restaurant
6  Sporting Goods, Fashion, Shoe Stores, Shopping...          shopping
7                Synagogues, Religious Organizations               NaN
8  Pubs, Restaurants, Italian, Bars, American (Tr...        restaurant
9  Ice Cream & Frozen Yogurt, Fast Food, Burgers,...        restaurant

Output with ice cream in the beginning:
                                       long_category    short_category
0  Doctors, Traditional Chinese Medicine, Naturop...  health & medical
1  Shipping Centers, Local Services, Notaries, Ma...          services
2  Department Stores, Shopping, Fashion, Home & G...          shopping
3  Restaurants, Food, Bubble Tea, Coffee & Tea, B...        restaurant
4                          Brewpubs, Breweries, Food               NaN
5  Burgers, Fast Food, Sandwiches, Food, Ice Crea...         ice cream
6  Sporting Goods, Fashion, Shoe Stores, Shopping...          shopping
7                Synagogues, Religious Organizations               NaN
8  Pubs, Restaurants, Italian, Bars, American (Tr...        restaurant
9  Ice Cream & Frozen Yogurt, Fast Food, Burgers,...         ice cream

